# Unreasonable growth of memory usage with spell checker in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, pyspark, spell-checking

I'm trying to write a simple tokenizer and spell checker with pyspark -v2.3. The input is not too big - around 64M of data. When I try to run with the spell correction option ON, the memory usage grows to fill my 32GB ram. I know the culprit is the python autocorrect.spell(w) method, but Cant figure out how to resolve the issue. Any help is welcome.

I launch the script using: 
spark-submit -v --master local[*] --conf "spark.driver.memory=16g"  --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=16"   pyspark_create_embeddings.py

Note that I dont get Java heap OOM exceptions. Does it mean that this is stack growth?

```
import autocorrect.spell
def tokenize(text_rdd, clean_html=False, tokenizer="twitter", remove_reps=True, spell_correct=True):

    print("Processing {} tokns".format(text_rdd.count()))

    if(remove_reps):
        text_rdd = text_rdd.map(lambda text : re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', text))

    tokens_rdd = text_rdd.map(lambda text: TweetTokenizer().tokenize(text))
    if spell_correct:
        tokens_rdd = tokens_rdd.map(lambda tokens: [spell(t) for t in tokens])
    #tokens_rdd = tokens_rdd.map(lambda tokens: [t for t in tokens])

    return tokens_rdd
```

Comment: What makes you think this is related to Spark at all? Based on the description it sounds more like an issue with library you use.

Comment: Likz @user9613318 said, you need to isolate the source of the problem which might come from the library that you are using.